# How to negotiate contract-to-hire offer with startup?

Tags: negotiation, startup, contractors, compensation, fulltime

I just got offered a contract with potential to full-time for a tech startup ( < 10 people), no 3rd party recruitment firm. I was sent an informal offer over e-mail which said 10-15 hrs/wk for $45-$55/hr. I asked if I could raise the time commitment, however the hiring manager said that he has a max monthly limit for payment.

My ideal scenario would be $60/hr for 20 hours, especially since this will be a 1099. This is based on a previous contract which was $60/hr with a compensation limit. I'm going to wait until I get the full contract to negotiate.

How would you approach negotiation?

Answer (score 5):

> How would you approach negotiation?

Personally, I'd shoot for the $60/hour you want, and adjust the hours worked as necessary to meet the hiring manager's monthly limit.

That way, if budgets loosen, you'll still be getting $60/hour.

Make sure your contract allows you to work for other companies in the hours you aren't working for this one.

Comment: So would it be appropriate to ask what the monthly limit is?